# sql query to replace column with same values if another column has duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update

have a table like the below:

```
id       Phone       
A        123456789        
B        123456789        
C        123456789        
D        989898987       
E        225897744
```

If the phone number is the same I need the id to be same in first table there are three id's (A, B, C) for same number. I need this to be related either A or B or C

```
id       Phone       
A        123456789        
A        123456789        
A        123456789        
D        989898987       
E        225897744
```

Please help me am not much aware of this type of hard query because am a beginner . Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you decide A for 123456789  and not B or C. Is there a date field that dictates that order. Or do you want it be an alphnumeric minimum value? Also please remove unnecessary tags. You are either using SQL Server or MySQL, not both.

Comment: based on last update if possbile, sir the need is like this if a parent has two students the parent id for both students should be the same but not the parent id is different so that each parent has multiple ids depends on how many children's. but since the phone number is the same we can use this to make parent id same for those phone number that's my need

Comment: That I get. What I don't get is why you decided to choose A over B or C for all instances of 123456789.

Comment: not like that of  x and y are siblings and their parents has two login x1 and y1, in database one of the common thing for both x and y is phone number. since parent need only on login for x and y, I need to make x1 or y1 ad parent id for x and y

Comment: Did Gordon's answer not work for you?

Comment: this  is what i tried  from his answer  select min(`parent_id`) over (partition by `mobileno`) as `parent_id`, `mobileno` from t;

Comment: i received this error ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by `mobileno`) as `parent_id`, `mobileno`
from t' at line 1

Comment: What version of my MySQL are you using?

Comment: Server version: 5.6.41-84.1-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.1, Revision b308619

Comment: Try new answers below

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select min(id) over (partition by phone) as id, phone
from t;
```

Or dispense with duplicates:

```
select min(id) as id, phone
from t
group by phone;
```

I see no reason to store duplicates in a table, so I am not proposing an `update` solution.

Comment: hi, the need is like this if a parent has two students the parent id for both students should be the same but not the parent id is different so that each parent has multiple ids depends on how many children's. but since the phone number is the same we can use this to make parent id same for those phone number that's my need

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `update` query for your purpose, that would work on any MySQL verion:

```
update mytable t
inner join (select phone, min(id) min_id from mytable group by phone) m
    on t.phone = m.phone and t.id <> m.min_id
set t.id = m.min_id
```

This works by self-joining the table with an aggregate query that gets the minimum `id` per `phone`: for rows where the `id` differs from the `min_id` of the same `phone`, the query updates the `id`.

Comment: sorry sir, this query makes parent id same for those  students with the same phone number but the problem is that the parent id which is made same is not among the parent's of those students. as I said for  x and y, I need to make x1 or y1 ad parent id for x and y for any other than x1 or y1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something along these lines

```
select t2.id, t1.phone
from your_table t1
inner join (select min(id) as id, phone 
            from your_table 
            group by phone) t2 on t2.phone=t1.phone
```